# Exactly how do backslashes work within backticks?

Tags: bash, escaping, backslash, backticks

From the [Bash FAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082):

> Backslashes (\) inside backticks are handled in a non-obvious manner:
>
> ```
>  $ echo "`echo \\a`" "$(echo \\a)"
>  a \a
>  $ echo "`echo \\\\a`" "$(echo \\\\a)"
>  \a \\a
> ```

But the FAQ does not break down the parsing rules that lead to this difference.  The only relevant quote from `man bash` I found was:

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, `, or .

The `"$(echo \\a)"` and `"$(echo \\\\a)"` cases are easy enough: Backslash, the escape character, is escaping itself into a literal backlash.  Thus every instance of `\\` becomes `\` in the output.  But I'm struggling to understand the analogous logic for the backtick cases.  What is the underlying rule and how does the observed output follow from it?

Finally, a related question... If you don't quote the backticks, you get a "no match" error:

```
$ echo `echo \\\\a`
-bash: no match: \a
```

What's happening in this case?

### update

Re: my main question, I have a theory for a set of rules that explains all the behavior, but still don't see how it follows from any of the documented rules in bash.  Here are my proposed rules....

Inside backticks, a backslash in front of a character simply returns that character.  Ie, a single backslash has no effect.  And this is true for all characters, *except* backlash itself and backticks.  In the case of backslash itself, `\\` becomes *an escaping backslash*.  It will escape its next character.

Let's see how this plays out in an example:

```
a=xx
echo "`echo $a`"      # prints the value of $a
echo "`echo \$a`"     # single backslash has no effect: equivalent to above
echo "`echo \\$a`"    # escaping backslash make $ literal
```

prints:

```
xx
xx
$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcwxDoMwFAPQvaewgFNU6k068BM5TUSaUH5A3D5EDKh48WDrGVFfq7z2/UHrM7rxrEHGDmd6zEtIRVE8sUlciezafru/r38PDekTCSN20th0eFGkDDpHW57gbw3NYSooGWLyxrt1YT2oVubm/WlfmYgBMRQuEms9AA)

Let's analyze the original examples from this perspective:

```
echo "`echo \\a`"
```

Here the `\\` produces an escaping backslash, but when we "escape" `a` we just get back `a`, so it prints `a`.

```
echo "`echo \\\\a`"
```

Here the first pair `\\` produces an escaping backslash which is applied to `\`, producing a literal backslash.  That is, the first 3 `\\\` become a single literal `\` in the output.  The remaining `\a` just produces `a`.  Final result is `\a`.

Comment: can't reproduce that error on bash 5.0.7, which version do you have?

Comment: @oguzismail `GNU bash, version 5.0.2(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0)`

Comment: That "no match" error looks like you have `failglob` set and for some reason bash is trying to treat `\a` as a filename pattern. I have no idea why it would do this.

Comment: Backslash inside backticks definitely escapes a backtick. Inside that new backtick expression, a double backslash is required to introduce another level of nested backticks.

Comment: @tripleee Good point, I updated my "update" section to include that.  I'm still not sure my theory is right, but it's the best I have so far that explains what I'm seeing.

Comment: I vaguely recall that backticks are generally similar to double quotes, but I don't have a reference, and may be mixing this with Perl's rules.

Comment: @Jonah your theory is the best I've seen so far. Thanks for doing the analysis. I noticed (and tested), and this follows from your theory, that `echo \`echo \\\a\`` also outputs `\a`.  Weird stuff. Now I understand better why so many say to use `$(...)` instead!

Comment: PS: I suggest you copy your theory into an answer and accept it, or at least let us upvote it.

Comment: @joanis Thanks.  I will do that if no one else answers.  I'm  hoping a true bash expert will see this and elaborate on the theory, connect it to documentation, etc.  I think my theory is *functionally* correct, at least for most cases, but I still feel I'm missing the full story.

Comment: OK, here's a kicker, consistent with your theory: you need 7 backslashes to get `\\a` as output! The first 4 give you a literal backslash, and as before you need at least three more before you get a second literal backslash.

Comment: Yes, I think my theory is good for explaining any number of such backslashes.  But things get interesting when you consider nested backticks, and escaped nested backticks: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY@9asNAEIR7PcVgF05A6BXcpEmTFHYTUKH7WUuHz7vi7oTip5dXNiSgag9u@L4Za/KwLHucB0JgpoS2w5jET45gwDTDye1m2CNPVt9c6LfU@Po@wzAoOzOShzXumqOyqj0@qV4hISOP5IKJTUVuEOy652lfZwht1@2qNc@eyNe4y3SIET2VJzklSQgXlIHuh0RgKaqJhp363k5E@CA79bAUZX7fKF7kk2pkhpeVrasCK3pbuwR3PWr4RyOsRf7@A/f/u1RzEW0RStNs9rSrblke "Bash – Try It Online")

Comment: I think that the `shopt -s failglob; echo $(<<<"\a" cat)` is wrongly parsed. Why does filename expansion triggers there? @joanis , the behavior also ahppens with `$(`, ex. `shopt -s failglob; echo $(echo "\\a")` I get `no match` error. This looks like a bug. filename expansion shouldn't happen on `\a` string, only when the argument after word splitting has `*` or `?` or `[`

Comment: @KamilCuk I can't reproduce your errors - in my bash 4.4.12 shell, both commands output `\a`.

Comment: Indeed `docker run -ti --rm bash:4.4.12 -c 'shopt -s failglob; echo $(<<<"\a" cat)'` works, but `docker run -ti --rm bash:5 -c 'shopt -s failglob; echo $(<<<"\a" cat)'` fails. Looks like a bug. At least it inconsistent between versions. 4.4.23 looks like the last working version.

Comment: @KamilCuk so this is a recently introduced bug. Rather disappointing I have to say, but I guess it's going to happen, with such complex software tools. Might be worth reporting to the bash bug tracker, assuming there is such a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic is quite simple as such. So we look at bash source code (4.4) itself

**subst.c:9273**

```c
case '`': /* Backquoted command substitution. */
{
    t_index = sindex++;

    temp = string_extract(string, &sindex, "`", SX_REQMATCH);
    /* The test of sindex against t_index is to allow bare instances of
        ` to pass through, for backwards compatibility. */
    if (temp == &extract_string_error || temp == &extract_string_fatal)
    {
    if (sindex - 1 == t_index)
    {
        sindex = t_index;
        goto add_character;
    }
    last_command_exit_value = EXECUTION_FAILURE;
    report_error(_("bad substitution: no closing \"`\" in %s"), string + t_index);
    free(string);
    free(istring);
    return ((temp == &extract_string_error) ? &expand_word_error
                                            : &expand_word_fatal);
    }

    if (expanded_something)
    *expanded_something = 1;

    if (word->flags & W_NOCOMSUB)
    /* sindex + 1 because string[sindex] == '`' */
    temp1 = substring(string, t_index, sindex + 1);
    else
    {
    de_backslash(temp);
    tword = command_substitute(temp, quoted);
    temp1 = tword ? tword->word : (char *)NULL;
    if (tword)
        dispose_word_desc(tword);
    }
    FREE(temp);
    temp = temp1;
    goto dollar_add_string;
}
```

As you can see calls a function `de_backslash(temp);` on the string which updates the string in c. The code the same function is below

**subst.c:1607**

```
/* Remove backslashes which are quoting backquotes from STRING.  Modifies
   STRING, and returns a pointer to it. */
char *
    de_backslash(string) char *string;
{
  register size_t slen;
  register int i, j, prev_i;
  DECLARE_MBSTATE;

  slen = strlen(string);
  i = j = 0;

  /* Loop copying string[i] to string[j], i >= j. */
  while (i < slen)
  {
    if (string[i] == '\\' && (string[i + 1] == '`' || string[i + 1] == '\\' ||
                              string[i + 1] == '$'))
      i++;
    prev_i = i;
    ADVANCE_CHAR(string, slen, i);
    if (j < prev_i)
      do
        string[j++] = string[prev_i++];
      while (prev_i < i);
    else
      j = i;
  }
  string[j] = '\0';

  return (string);
}
```

The above just does simple thing if there is `\` character and the next character is `\` or backtick or `$`, then skip this `\` character and copy the next character

So if convert it to python for simplicity

```py
text = r"\\\\$a"

slen = len(text)
i = 0
j = 0
data = ""
while i < slen:
    if (text[i] == '\\' and (text[i + 1] == '`' or text[i + 1] == '\\' or
                             text[i + 1] == '$')):
        i += 1
    data += text[i]
    i += 1

print(data)
```

The output of the same is `\\$a`. And now lets test the same in bash

```sh
$ a=xxx

$ echo "$(echo \\$a)"
\xxx

$ echo "`echo \\\\$a`"
\xxx
```

Answer (score 4):

Did some more research to find the reference and rule of what is happening. From the [GNU Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) it states

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash
>   retains its literal meaning except when followed by ‘$’, ‘`’, or ‘\’.
>   The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the command
>   substitution. When using the $(command) form, all characters between
>   the parentheses make up the command; none are treated specially.

In other words \, \$, and ` inside of `` are processed by the CLI parser before the command substitution. Everything else is passed to the command substitution for processing.

Let's step through each example from the question. After the # I put how the command substitution was processed by the CLI parser before `` or $() is executed.

Your first example explained.

```
$ echo "`echo \\a`"   # echo \a
 a 
$ echo "$(echo \\a)"  # echo \\a
 \a
```

Your second example explained:

```
$ echo "`echo \\\\a`"   # echo \\a
 \a 
$ echo "$(echo \\\\a)"  # echo \\\\a
 \\a
```

Your third example:

```
a=xx
$ echo "`echo $a`"    # echo xx 
xx
$ echo "`echo \$a`"   # echo $a
xx
echo "`echo \\$a`"    # echo \$a
$a
```

Your third example using $()

```
$ echo "$(echo $a)"     # echo $a
xx
$ echo "$(echo \$a)"    # echo \$a
$a
$ echo "$(echo \\$a)"   # echo \\$a
\xx
```