# How to handle spaces in MV command

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have the following script that renames files based on a specific file name string. The script was working fine until I had to apply it to a directory that contains a folder name with a space.

Script:

```
for file in `find /home/splunkLogs/Captin/PPM\ Images/PXT  -type f -name '*.jpg'`; do mv -v "$file" "${file/-0.jpg/_Page_1.jpg}"; done
```

You'll notice the file name "PPM Images", which has a space. I added a backslash so the path would be readable, but I get the error "mv: cannot stat /home/splunkLogs/Captin/PPM: No such file or directory. I also tried putting the folder name in quotes in the path and received the same error. Can anyone guide me with a solution for handling filename spaces with the MV command?

Comment: You don't read lines with `for` this ain't `python`

Comment: @Whoever closed this: this is asking for move _and rename_.  The other answers don't have that detail.

Comment: @rtx13: I don't have a view on the closure, but bear in mind that closures do not have to be precise. If proposed duplicate(s) would get a question author 90% of the way to a solution, then they are good enough to close the question, in my view. We generally expect question authors to do some legwork with answers anyway - surely we want to discourage copy-paste usage of answers from here, which can lead to all sorts of problems, e.g. with security.

Comment: @rtx13 ... this is a site for Q&A that are relevant to more than one person; anyone who comes here with an expectation to get a tailored response to their exact use-case is doing it wrong. Both offered up duplicates should make it abundantly clear how to work around the issue without spelling the whole thing out verbatim.

Comment: (note to self 3ddf25ca491b60fa4af9a1c2927b23eb)

Comment: @Whoever linked other questions:  how is the linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447644/exactly-how-do-backslashes-work-within-backticks question relevant to this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So do not read lines using `for`. Read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 .

```
find /home/splunkLogs/Captin/PPM\ Images/PXT  -type f -name '*.jpg' |
while IFS= read -r file; do
     mv -v "$file" "${file/-0.jpg/_Page_1.jpg}"
done
```

or better:

```
find /home/splunkLogs/Captin/PPM\ Images/PXT  -type f -name '*.jpg' -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
     mv -v "$file" "${file/-0.jpg/_Page_1.jpg}"
done
```

Do not use backticks `. Using `$(...)` instead is greatly preferred.